торговать газетной водой (strange phrase)
This is from РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

его издательство, бойко торговавшее либеральной газетной водой, дѣлало
ещё большіе обороты съ православіемъ и вѣрноподанностью

What can либеральная газетная вода mean? His newspaper made a lot of money peddling the liberal newspaper "snake oil" (there is such an English expression), and then boosted its turnover much higher when it started selling Orthodoxy and loyalty to the throne?

Thanks for "snail oil". Never heard it before. Фуфло чистой воды.

@V.V. I've never heard of фуфло́ , but I thought I should give the stress here, in case anyone's interested, and state that it is жаргон, i.e. it is belongs to criminal argot.

I mean "it belongs to". I started writing something else, and then left the "is" in.

“Water” may be used metaphorically to mean “a lot of words without substance”. The most frequent use is probably in relation to student’s writing: «в дипломе не хватает десяти страниц, налью воды».
If that’s the case, not sure if “snake oil” would be the correct idiom. “Word salad” or “hot air” might be more appropriate.
